# How do I create a remote branch?

Tags: git, github

If I create branches on my local git repos like so:

`git checkout -b test`

then do a push

`git push`

I don't actually see the new branch `test` in my GitHub page. How do I make my remote branches mirror my local branches?

### Update

When I made a commit (even though there were no changes) and ran:

`git push origin test`

that worked. But is that the correct way? Shouldn't a `git push` push all local changes to the remote repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
git push -u origin test:test
```

To create the remote branch.

> But is that the correct way?

Yes.

> Shouldn't a *git push* push all local changes to the remote repository?

Only if the branch was setup to track to remote branch in the first place. Your branch isn't tracking anything until you explicitly push it once.

Comment: Nice. this worked and told me that the remote branch is now tracking the local branch. But just for the sake of clarity, what does the `-u` flag do?

Comment: @Maiasaura It sets an upstream tracking reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to push new local branches explicitly:

```
git push origin test:test
```

Otherwise Git would push any (temporary) local branch you created3